# What's eating my internet bandwidth? Incompatibility between nethogs and System Monitor's Network History

Tags: system-monitor, bandwidth

When I open System Monitor, the Network History shows that there are **~64 KiB/s** being downloaded constantly. And it's not my doing! So I wanted to see which application is downloading and I installed nethogs.

But according to nethogs my system's download speed is less than **1 KB/sec** in total!! What's going on? How can I make sure who's telling the truth? Personally I trust System Monitor as I can completely feel the lack of bandwidth. Then I must ask how can I find the process responsible for the download?

Here's how I ran nethogs:

```
$ sudo nethogs eth0
```

And there are only two network interfaces on my machine, **eth0** and **lo**, none of which is downloading the 64K!

Comment: You can use `iftop` as an additional source...

Comment: But `iftop` does not tell me which application is downloading, does it?

Comment: Use `iftop -nPB` to look up the local port, then use sudo `netstat -tup` to locate the process "owning" that port.

Comment: What if there's no port? `iftop`'s first row is: `192.168.1.1                => 224.0.0.1` and it's eating most of my bandwidth! I know `224.0.0.1` is broadcast IP but why am I downloading from it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pulseaudio isn't set to broadcast in your sound settings. I had the same "issue" with about 200KB/s showing up and nothing shows up in nethogs.